# for loop does not check if condition after looping once in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here loop runs once and checks every `if` condition but next time it does not check any `if` condition.

```
function change()
{
alert("get it");
//a=document.forms[0]["hid"].value;
c=document.forms[0]["new"].value;
alert(c);
//var array = JSON.parse("[" + c + "]");
//var array = [c];
var array1 = new Array();
array1 = c.slice(1,c.length-1);
alert(array1);

array1 = array1.split(",")
//arr[]=array.toString();
alert("message"+array1);
alert(array1.length);

for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {

switch (array1[i]) {
   case "seat 2":
        match = "seat 2";
        break;
   case "seat 5":
        match = "seat 5";
        break;
   case "seat 7":
        match = "seat 7"
        break;
   case "seat 6":
        match = "seat 6" 
        break;       
   }
   alert("matching"+ match );
   document.getElementById(match).checked = true;
   document.getElementById(match).disabled = true;
   }


    }
```

so, now how can i get out from problem. here array1 value is seat2, seat 5, seat 7. which is extracted from a text box. and in that text box's value i got from session.getAttribute("check44"). so help me. i m using this code for my project.

can contact me throgh rk8650@gmail.com

Comment: why java and jsp tag? Also can you complete your whole for loop?

Comment: I'd hate to think what this would look like if you had 100 seats.

Comment: Your array isn't an array. It's an object. Your code should fail there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var array3 = ['seat 2', 'seat 5', 'seat 7'];


for (i = 0; i < array3.length; i++)

{

  alert(array3[i]);

  if (array3[i] == "seat5")

  {

    alert("match 1");

    document.getElementById("seat 1").checked = true;

    document.getElementById("seat 1").disabled = true;
  } else if (array3[i] == "seat 2")

  {
    alert("match 2");
    document.getElementById("seat 2").checked = true;
    document.getElementById("seat 2").disabled = true;
  } else if (array3[i] == "seat 3") {
    alert("match 3");
    document.getElementById("seat 3").checked = true;
    document.getElementById("seat 3").disabled = true;
  } else if (array3[i] == "seat 4") {
    alert("match 4");
    document.getElementById("seat 4").checked = true;
    document.getElementById("seat 4").disabled = true;
  } else if (array3[i] == "seat 5") {
    alert("match 5");
    document.getElementById("seat 5").checked = true;
    document.getElementById("seat 5").disabled = true;
  } else if (array3[i] == "seat 6") {
    alert("match 6");
    document.getElementById("seat 6").checked = true;
    document.getElementById("seat 6").disabled = true;
  } else if (array3[i] == "seat 7") {
    alert("match 7");
    document.getElementById("seat 7").checked = true;
    document.getElementById("seat 7").disabled = true;
  } else if (array3[i] == "seat 8") {
    alert("match 8");
    document.getElementById("seat 8").checked = true;
    document.getElementById("seat 8").disabled = true;
  } else if (array3[i] == "seat 9") {
    alert("match 9");
    document.getElementById("seat 9").checked = true;
    document.getElementById("seat 9").disabled = true;
  } else {
    alert("stucked");
  }

}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' id='seat 1'>Seat 1
<br>
<input type='checkbox' id='seat 2'>Seat 2
<br>
<input type='checkbox' id='seat 3'>Seat 3
<br>
<input type='checkbox' id='seat 4'>Seat 4
<br>
<input type='checkbox' id='seat 5'>Seat 5
<br>
<input type='checkbox' id='seat 6'>Seat 6
<br>
<input type='checkbox' id='seat 7'>Seat 7
<br>
<input type='checkbox' id='seat 8'>Seat 8
<br>
<input type='checkbox' id='seat 9'>Seat 9
```

I found 2 issues with your code. Once I fixed these 2 issues, the code snippet worked as expected.

First, you need to use the keyword `var` whenever you want to declare a new variable. In your case, the array you declared at the begining was not created properly.

Also, string arrays are declared with square brackets, not curly brackets.

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
```

not

```
var cars = {"Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"};   //curly brackets are for objects.
```

Also, it is a good practice to declare the iterator in a for loop like so:

```
for(var i=0; i<array3.length;i++)
```

instead of

```
for(i=0; i<array3.length;i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to define your array as

```
array3 = ["seat 2","seat 5","seat 7"]; // notice [] for arrays, {} for objects
```

Second, you can condense your code to

```
for (i = 0; i < array3.length; i++) {
  alert( array3[i] );
  if(array3[i] == "seat 5" ) {
        alert("match 1");
        document.getElementById("seat 1").checked = true;
        document.getElementById("seat 1").disabled = true;
   } else {
        alert ("match " + array3[i]);
        document.getElementById(array3[i]).checked = true;
        document.getElementById(array3[i]).disabled = true;
   }
}
```

Since, except `seat 5`, the names of the elements match the values from the array, there's no need to check the values explicitly and the `if` blocks can be done away with a single `else` block.

---

Using a *switch-case* instead of *if-else* blocks

```
array3 = ["seat 2","seat 5","seat 7"];

for (i = 0; i < array3.length; i++) {
  switch (array3[i]) {
       case "seat 2":
            match = "seat 2";
            break;
       case "seat 5":
            match = "seat 1";
            break;
       case "seat 7":
            match = "seat 7"   
  }
  alert( match );
  document.getElementById(match).checked = true;
  document.getElementById(match).disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: okk fine but i want more if condition for more values.
for two values i can use if and else but what if i want to use more if conditions for more values

Comment: In that case, use a *switch* statement instead.

Comment: please give a example for atleast 3 if condition

Comment: thnxx sir ur code is right but my problem still have not solved
because i m using an array which have some values and through that i want to extract values and then check to if condition...

Comment: What you are saying does not match the sample you've shared in your question. Can you update your question with more details on what problem you're facing?

Comment: look i have edited my question
in this m using the array1 which have values seat 1, seat 5, seat 7
if u really want to help me then add me rk8650@gmail.com in gmail

Answer (score 0):

1. You forgot a right bracket after `if (array3[i] == "seat 8"`.
2. As @Mouser said it isn't an array. Use rectangle brackets.

   `array3 = ["seat 2", "seat 5", "seat 7"];`